# Exact Duplicate Routing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

If a question is closed on SO due to the existence of an exact duplicate of said question there should be a link to the latter from the closed question so people can quickly get to the answer they're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is. It is put at the top of the question by the community user.

Comment: Not all duplicates have community user help, yet. Can links be given in the "closed as exact duplicate by [...]" message box? I think user Ólafur Waage was asking in question 19246 -http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19246/can-i-please-select-a-current-duplicate-when-closing-a-question/

Comment: This is not true. Sometime there are multiple links and they are labeled as **possible** duplicates so there is no way to tell which one the community thought was the duplicate.

See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795551/why-is-a-valid-function-identifier. In fact, in this case, neither is a duplicate of the question although they are duplicates of each other.

Comment: So the links are there, as asked for in the question and as said in my answer. And your objection is that I am somehow wrong because you feel that the people who closed the question supplied the wrong duplicate question links?