# Can I please select a current duplicate when closing a question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I've read somewhere that it's to prevent lazy users selecting that one and not checking if it is actually a dupe.

I don't buy that one bit.

**Isn't the system supposed to trust us?**

Why hinder the users who want to help out by putting an obstacle of either searching in that box or typing out the ID of the current one.

Comment: I want you to have my babies.

Comment: http://www.santharia.com/pictures/aragorn/aragorn_pics/centaur.jpg

Comment: Come over, just mind the volcanoes and polar bears.

Comment: I always just right click `->` copy link address. Then just paste that.

Comment: Would this be a question on the other side of users wanting a link to the duplicates? - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17926/exact-duplicate-routing

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's rather ridiculous to have to copy and paste the exact question text (otherwise, more often than not, it won't find it from selected keywords) and then finding it at the bottom of the list anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can drag the link and drop it in the textbox. Works on Chrome, Safari on Windows, OS X.

Comment: Just tried it, Firefox ubuntu and only thing it does is goto the link.

Comment: Ya gotta finagle it a bit, and that makes it more work than Olafur's click-and-forget it suggestion. Still, a good tip.

Answer (score 2):

Hover your pointer over one of them and just type the serial number into the search box, it'll pop right up.

But you should open them first to check that they really are the same--unless you know the one in question very well (how we love you 1669). Titles can be misleading.

Comment: In case anyone was curious like me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669

Comment: ... list of resources for writing compilers

Comment: I assume that this one often comes up as a duplicate.

Comment: We see a pretty basic "How do I write a compiler?" of "I want to make a new language" type question every week or so.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy/paste the question number into the search box, the list will consist of just the right question. If you're not first to the close and want to "second" the votes already there, just type or copy/paste from the link provided.

Some of the votes to close have been the result of herd mentality, so no, I don't trust others to check and/or think about the decisions they are making. Diffusion of responsibility kicks in around the 3rd vote. The 4th and 5th voters just follow the crowd because they can.

Comment: "The 4th and 5th voters just follow the crowd because they can." - they do? I don't. Who does that?

Comment: I'm glad you don't. The phenomenon is easy to spot. You have a closed question as duplicate, then you read the "dupe" and see that it isn't really a duplicate. Then the unedited question that was closed as a duplicate now has 2 votes to reopen.

Comment: I've actually seen quite a few questions where 2-3 duplicate links have been posted in comments, and the first three or so close votes will all reference the first one (even if a better match has been found later). Hard to know for sure though what folks are doing; it always comes down to a judgment call.

Comment: +1 I just use the question # because it's faster/easier, and I'm lazy.